# why do we say Vasicek interest rate model has a closed form solution

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, closed-form, stochastic-integrals, stochastic-differential-equations

Vasicek interest rate model solution has the form of:

[image]

and Cox-Ingersoll-Ross (CIR) interest rate model solution has the form of:

[image]

As we can see both models have dW term at the end, why do we say that Vasicek interest rate model has a closed form solution ?

Answer (score 1):

The Vasicek solution is closed form because the stochastic integral

$$I(a)= \int_0^t e^{as} \, dW_s$$

has a deterministic integrand and the moments can be obtained in closed form

$$E[I(a)] = 0, \\ \text{var}[I(a)] = \int_0^t e^{2as} \, dt = \frac{e^{2at}-1}{2a}$$

Comment: can you please show me how is the stochastic integral for Vasicek has a deterministic integrand ? I think the moments for CIR can also be obtained in closed form. When we say closed form does it mean that it's no longer in the SDE form ? if that's the case why would Vasicek solution still be in SDE form ?

Comment: I mean $e^{as}$ is not stochastic.  Then we get the exact solution for $E[r(t)]$ and $\text{var}[r(t)]$ and in fact know it is normally distributed.  Can you tell me the exact variance of $r(t)$ for CIR?  Also do you know how the variance of $I(a)$ was obtained as above?

Comment: It's possible CIR has a closed-form as well. I believe closed-form means the probability distribution or at least the moments of the solution are known in terms of recognizable elementary functions.

Comment: I believe the variance above is obtained through Ito isometry. The exact variance for CIR model is actually known as:

Var$[r_{t}|r_{0}]=r_{0}{\frac  {\sigma ^{2}}{a}}(e^{{-at}}-e^{{-2at}})+{\frac  {b\sigma ^{2}}{2a}}(1-e^{{-at}})^{2}$.

Comment: I think I am having trouble understanding what is considered as "known" or closed solution. Is it all come down to the distribution ? The expectation of CIR is zero. But we don't know the distribution of the variance for CIR therefore CIR doesn't have a closed solution ?

Answer (score 1):

Intuitively, you can think of a form of $r = f(t) + X$. Where $f(t)$ is a deterministic function of $t$ and $X$ follows $N(\mu, \sigma^2)$

For Vasicek, $X \sim N(0, \frac{\sigma^2(1 - e^{-2at})}{2a})$, $f(t) = r(0)e^{-at} + \theta(1 - e^{-at})$

So basically the model tells you $r \sim N(r(0)e^{-at} + \theta(1 - e^{-at}), \frac{\sigma^2(1 - e^{-2at})}{2a})$